# How to adjust my WebViewActivity class to open market:// and intent:// links

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webview

I'm building an app that integrates different offer walls, most of them implemented by SDK, but some of them need to be opened by direct link, so I need to open these in Web View.

I was able to open the offer walls by direct link, however, I've noticed that some of the offers inside them contain market:// or intent:// links and I receive a big error when trying to click one of those links.

**This is my WebViewActivity.java:**

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String WEBSITE_ADDRESS = "website_address";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String url  = getIntent().getStringExtra(WEBSITE_ADDRESS);
        if (url == null || url.isEmpty()) finish();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.nyc_poi_webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

As mentioned, it works for HTTP and HTTPS links, but not for the market:// or intent://

Can you please give me some tips on how to achieve what I want?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method to deny the error. Below I have given an example.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getScheme().equals("market")) {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                Activity host = (Activity) view.getContext();
                host.startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                // Google Play app is not installed, you may want to open the app store link
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                view.loadUrl("http://play.google.com/store/apps/" + uri.getHost() + "?" + uri.getQuery());
                return false;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: where should I add this? In my MainActivity class?

Comment: you can use it in your WebViewActivity .